# What does params do in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class D {
  public params: any;
  ....
  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }
  get businessLine(): string {
   if (this.params.businessLine)
    return this.params.data.businessLine;
  }
 }
```

The caller does pass a businessLine to this class. However, it does not pass `data`. Is this `data` a keyword?

The sample caller code is here,

```
 cellRenderParams: {
   businesLine: this.businessLine
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. data is not any key word
2. the params passed to agInit(params: any) is an object  like {data:businessLine}
3. you could reaname params in agInit(params: any) like _params for just clearity sake

Comment: There is another case `this.params.businessLine`. Why does this one not have `.data`.

Comment: 4.  this.params.businessLine means you check  if you params has businessLine 
 like this {businessLine:"examle data"} or  not  like {} ,{blabla :"",}